# MARIADB ERROR 1064 (42000) when CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, ddl, create-table

When I try to create a table:

```
MariaDB [heladeria]> create table sabores ('Id_sabores' int NOT
NULL,'sab_nombre' varchar(255) NOT NULL, 'calorias' varchar(255) NOT
NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Id_sabores));
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error
in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
server version for the right syntax to use near ''Id_sabores' int NOT
NULL,'sab_nombre' varchar(255) NOT NULL, 'calorias' varchar' at line 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes (`'`) are used to denote string literals, not object (in this case - column) names. Just remove them and you should be fine:

```
create table sabores (
    Id_sabores int NOT NULL,
    sab_nombre varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    calorias varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (Id_sabores)
);
```

Comment: Thank you Mureinik , that is fast , it work , but before a create another table with the quotes  **``**  and it works.. Maybe MariaDB woks with this quotes      **``**    and not with this `''`... anyway thanks again..

Comment: Maybe MariaDB woks with this quotes      ``   and not with this `''`...

Comment: @TOMAS backticks (`) are used to escape object names - they are perfectly fine to use (although they are redundant in this case). Regular quotes (') are something completely different.